# Is there a faster way to check if thousands of NSManagedObject items exist?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsfetchrequest

I'll use the example of a Google Reader client here, since that's what I'm actually doing...

I'm pulling in (potentially thousands of) items from a Google Reader account, and I'm wondering if there's a faster way to go about checking if I've already got an item (NSManagedObject) in the data store.  Google Reader gives each item a unique string ID, which I'm storing in my NSManagedObjects.  Here are the stripped down basics of what I do when importing.  Note that I do use background threads, but I've stripped them out here for the sake of clarity.

Could I be doing this more efficiently?

```
- (void)importBatchOfItems:(NSArray *)itemsFromGoogleReader isLastBatch:(BOOL)isLastBatch {
  for (NSDictionary *item in *itemsFromGoogleReader) {
    NSManagedObject *feedItem = [self feedItemWithId:[item valueForKey:@"GoogleReaderItemID"]];
    if (feedItem == nil) {
      feedItem = [self insertFeedItem];
    }

    // ... do some stuff with feedItem
  }

  BOOL saveIntervalElapsed = (([NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - self.lastBatchSave) >= kBatchSaveInterval);

  if (saveIntervalElapsed || isLastBatch) {
    [self saveContext];
  }
}

- (NSManagedObject *)feedItemWithId:(NSString *)itemId {
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id = %@", itemId];

  [self.uniqueItemFetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
  NSArray *items = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:self.uniqueItemFetchRequest error:nil];

  if ([items count] > 0) {
    return [items objectAtIndex:0];
  } else {
    return nil;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Apple docs for [Efficiently Importing Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html) they have several different ways of importing data for different scenarios with code snippets.

Comment: Thanks.  That's pretty much exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that will speed up this code (at the expense of some memory usage) is to pull *all* potential matches out of your data store into a set or array and query that set to see if an object with your target ID is in it. Fetch requests in Core Data are *much* slower than the equivalent query against a set of objects.

```
- (NSManagedObject *)feedItemWithId:(NSString *)itemId {
  NSArray *fetchedObjects; // Assume this has already been generated

   NSUInteger i = [array indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
     if ([idx id] = itemID)            
       return YES;
     else
       return NO;
    }];

  if (i != NSNotFound)
    return [array objectAtIndex:i];
  else
    return nil;
}
```

This code was written in place, so it may not work as written. Also, there's certainly clever ways to speed this up, but as shown it should run significantly faster than individual fetch requests.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I may give it a shot, but it doesn't seem like this would be effective after a certain number of objects.  There's a real possibility that I'll have 5,000 or even 10,000 objects to check against.  Is a Core Data fetch request really slower than iterating over 10,000 objects in an array?  It seems like there ought some optimizations behind the scenes that would make a fetch request faster.

Comment: A fetch request would be slower. For every request you are asking performing a new SQLite query. I/O operations are expensive.

Comment: What I'd do is set up a monstrous test database and try both ways out. Iterating over the array is almost guaranteed to be faster, but it could cause memory issues.